# Symfony checkboxes lists twig rendering

Tags: php, mysql, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm quite new to Symfony and I have a specific question.
I have a form for a job application where the applicant can choose competencies linked to categories.

Entities:

Application linked to Competence as many to many

Compentence linked to Category as Many to One

So in ApplicationType I have:

```
->add('competences', EntityType::class, array(
    'class'        => 'SanOffresBundle:Competence',
    'label' => 'Compétences (sélectionnez-en autant que vous voulez)',
    'choice_label' => 'nom',
    'multiple'     => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'query_builder' => function (CompetenceRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('cc')
        ->orderBy('cc.nom', 'ASC');},
    'group_by' => function($val, $key, $index) {
        return $val->getCategorie()->getNom();},        
    ))
```

With this code and variations I get:

- 'expanded' => false : a menu with competences sorted by category, but the categories are not in alphabetical order. This would be an acceptable alternative if the categories were sorted, but with more than 100 competences to choose from, it's not user friendly.
- 'expanded' => true : a list of competences checkboxes displayed grouped by categories, but the categories are not shown.

Would anybody have an idea?

Comment: Which one do you want to render, select which is like you want to ordered or checkboxes?

Comment: competences as checkboxes, grouped by categories, with the name of the categories displayed as titles of each group of checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to change order in secect with all `Competence` than you probably should extend your query builder with join

```
'query_builder' => function (CompetenceRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('cc')
               ->join('cc.category', 'cat') //something like that
               ->orderBy('cat.name', 'ASC')->addOrderBy('cc.nom', 'ASC');
}
```

another way would be to try `@ORM\OrderBy({...})` Annotation in your relations between `Compentence` and `Category`. [See link](http://ormcheatsheet.com/#panel132-1)

> 'expanded' => true : a list of competences checkboxes displayed grouped by categories, but the categories are not shown.

Which is correct since it's inherited option from `ChoiceType`. Group by works only if you render it as a `<SELECT>` dropdown where you can make use of `<optgroup>` for grouping. I think there's no way to get a bunch (list) of checkboxes with any grouping from symfony's FormTypes out of the box..at least without any extra offer.

Of cource you can create your own FormType and extend Twig-Widgets an so on. ...Or you could try to get desired look with [Collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) of (embedet) Forms ...but that are just thoughts since I do not know how your entities and their relations look like.

Comment: thanks a lot, the code worked ! The ORM tip is nice, I will surely use it somewhere in my project, it looks handy.